# Indexes on GROUP BY / MIN query on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, group-by, indexing

On a larger table (approx. .5 mil rows growing) I'm running following query taking quite a long time:

```
SELECT track, MIN(time) as t, buse, serviceid 
FROM depart 
WHERE `to` IS NOT NULL AND platform_id = 1025 AND time > 741 
GROUP BY serviceid
```

What would be a good index to support running this query fast? So far it uses the `platform_id` index with `where`, `filesort` and `temp`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Uses only platform_id index

Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: Is there an index on column `serviceid`?

Comment: Please be aware your usage of `group by` is basically wrong but accepted nevertheless by MySQL: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan - yes, but is not even in `possible_keys` column of EXPLAIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right indexing approach depends on the distribution of the data.  If only one row has a platform of 1025 then the situation is different from when all rows have a platform of 1025.

Making reasonable assumptions, you probably want an index on (platform, time).  If `to` is typically NULL, then the index (platform, to, time) might be an improvement.

The way the index will be used is that MySQL will find the values in the index that satisfy the `where` clause.  It will then read in every page for those records to get the rest of the variables and process the query.  Assuming there are a few hundred records that meet the criteria, this should significantly speed up the query.

Answer (score 0):

try this :s

```
SELECT track, MIN(time) as t, buse,DISTINCT serviceid 
FROM depart 
WHERE `to` IS NOT NULL AND platform_id = 1025 AND time > 741
```

Comment: that goes to syntax error, moving DISTINCT serviceid at the first placedoesn't return the same thing, I need to select distinct serviceids and then the minimum (so more rows), this query returns only one row